# How to change the directory in the httpd.conf file to the main index file from OpenEdX?

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, letsencrypt

my main goal is to setup a secure SSL Connection for my Open EdX System. I am using the Open EdX Version from Bitnami. To get a certified SSL certificate I want to use Let's Encrypt. Bitnami already delivers a fully functional "ready-to-use" Script. After running the Script and editing the httpd.conf file (replacing demo content as "example.com" with my domain ...) my Server has a certified SSL certificate, but there comes the Problem why I am asking this question.
When I now open my website I can't use the EdX System, I only see a Welcome (Placeholder) Page. 
*Something like "Awesome! Open edX is now installed.".*

I've tried to solve the Problem on my own and I realized that in the httpd.conf (apache config file) is an entry for the main serving directory. A quick look into the directory and there was the same Placeholder website.

Then I tried to change the path to one of the many index.html pages the bitnami EdX Version is using. The problem is there are alot and none of them worked.

Has anybody an Idea to where I have to change the Path to use the SSL cert and "redirect" to the right dir?

Thank you for you help,
Elias

Comment: You may want to look at the [Open edX/SSL documentation for Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/edx/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/). If you can access the Welcome page with SSL, you may want to then have a look at the [Open edX documentation](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/) to help configure your website.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thank you for you answer. I tried some of the information suggested in the edX/SSL Link. I might have found a solution, I think I messed the path up. Unfortunately I requested to many certs from Let's Encrypt, so I have to wait a week to try my solutions.